# Why is it considered that $ | \mathbb{Q} | = | \mathbb{N} | $ is true, but $ | \mathbb{R} | = | \mathbb{N} | $ is wrong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Please clarify why $|\mathbb{Q}| = |\mathbb{N}|$, but $|\mathbb{R}| > |\mathbb{N}|$?  Why do following arguments about $|\mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{N}|$ are wrong?

Two sets are equinumerous if there is a bijection between their elements. That is, each element of one set is in one-to-one correspondence with an element from the second set.

The cardinality of the set $|A|= |\mathbb{N}|$ if the elements of the set $A$ can be enumerated, that is, there is a bijection $A  \longleftrightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

It is known that $|\mathbb{Q}| = |\mathbb{N}|$, since it can be numbered by traversing the diagonals $i=1,\ldots,\infty$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
   i=1:\;& \frac{1}{1} \mapsto 1;\\
   i=2:\;& \frac{1}{2} \mapsto 2;\; \frac{2}{1} \mapsto 3;\\
   i=3:\;& \frac{1}{3} \mapsto 4;\; \frac{3}{1} \mapsto 5;\\
   i=4:\;& \frac{1}{4} \mapsto 6;\; \frac{2}{3} \mapsto 7;\; \frac{3}{2} \mapsto 8;\; \frac{4}{1} \mapsto 9;\\
   \ldots
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Well, let's denote $\mathbb{R}_{(0,1)}$ is the set of all real numbers on $(0,1)$ and try to enumerate them.

For this, we introduce the concept of *depth* of a number. A real number $r \in (0,1)$ has *depth* $i$ if its unique prefix, sufficient for unambiguous recognition of the number, has length $i$. For example, the number $0.0123000 \ldots $ has *depth* $4$, and the number $0.12000 \ldots $ has *depth* $2$.

Denote by $\mathbb{R}_{(0,1)}^{i}$ the subset of all numbers from $\mathbb{R}_{(0,1)}$ with *depth* $i$.
Obviously, $\mathbb{R}_{(0,1)}^{i}$ is a finite set for any fixed $i$, and hence it is enumerable set. Therefore, there is bijection $\mathbb{R}_{(0,1)}^{i} \longleftrightarrow  \mathbb{N}^i, \; \mathbb{N}^i \subset \mathbb{N}$. Consequently there exists a bijection $\mathbb{R}_{(0,1)} \longleftrightarrow \mathbb{N}$.
Hence:
$$ |\mathbb{R}_{(0,1)]}| = |\mathbb{N}| $$

Example:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
i=1:\;& 0.1 \mapsto 1;\; 0.2 \mapsto 2;\; 0.3 \mapsto 3;\; 0.4 \mapsto 4;\; 0.5 \mapsto 5;\; 0.6 \mapsto 6;\; 0.7 \mapsto 7;\; 0.8 \mapsto 8;\; 0.9 \mapsto 9;\\
i=2:\;& 0.01 \mapsto 10;\; 0.02 \mapsto 11;\; 0.03 \mapsto 12, \ldots,  0.99 \mapsto 110; \\
& \ldots
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Now let's try to number all real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

We can extend the definition of *depth* of a number and assume that *depth* of $i$ can be not only in one direction (to the right), but also in the other (to the left)

Let's introduce the pair $(i, j)$ where $i$ is the *depth of the number to the left*, and $j$ is the *depth of the number to the right*, let's call such a pair the *radius* of the number. For example, for the number $ \ldots 00012345,810000 \ldots $ we have *radius* $ (5,2) $, and for the number $ \ldots 000012,9000 \ldots $ we have *radius* $(2,1)$.

We denote by $\mathbb{R}^{(i, j)}$ the subset of all numbers from $ \mathbb{R}$ with *radius* $(i, j)$.

$\mathbb{R}^{(i, j)}$ is a finite set for any fixed $ i, j $ and hence enumerable.
Therefore, there is bijection $\mathbb {R}^{(i, j)} \longleftrightarrow \mathbb {N}^{(i, j)}, \; \mathbb{N}^{(i, j)} \subset \mathbb{N} $.
Hence there is a bijection $\mathbb{R} \longleftrightarrow \mathbb{N} $.

Hence:
$$ | \mathbb{R} | = | \mathbb{N} | $$
What is wrong.

Let's call our finite set $\mathbb{N}^{i}$ (or $ \mathbb{N}^{(i, j)}$) the *package*.

In case of proof, $ | \mathbb{Q} | = | \mathbb{N} | $ our *package* is the diagonal elements, the number of which in each new *package* increases by $ 1 $

In the case of the statement that $ | \mathbb{R} | = | \mathbb{N} | $ our *package* is all possible numbers with *depth* $ i $ and the size of the next *package* increases not by $ 1 $, but times.

But does this limit the construction of a bijection? What is the fundamental difference?
Indeed, in both cases we have a union of an infinite sequence of disjoint finite sets.

Why is it considered that $ | \mathbb{Q} | = | \mathbb{N} | $ is true, but $ | \mathbb{R} | = | \mathbb{N} | $ is wrong?

P.S. If you are asking what is the depth of $1/3$? What is the depth of the integer $33333(3)$?

Comment: "Hence there is a bijection $\mathbb{R}\leftrightarrow\mathbb{N}$". That assertion simply does not follow. Natural numbers have only finitely many digits;  you never reach any natural number that "maps"  to $\frac{1}{3}=0.333333\ldots$, which does not lie in any of your $\mathbb{R}^{(i,j)}$. As to the question in the title: because one can prove it is so.

Comment: What is the depth of $\frac13?$ Of $\pi?$ The real numbers with a finite depth are all rationals of the form $\frac{m}{10^n},$ which is not even all rational numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by the integer $33333(3)$?

Comment: You’ve made up a notation if you think $33333(3)$ means anything.

Comment: For exactly the same reason that we think that $|-1|=|1|$ is true, but $|1|=|2|$ is wrong.

Comment: Integers have only finitely many nonzero digits. There is no integer whose decimal representation includes infinitely many threes. The set of integer *sequences* is uncountable and has the same cardinality as  $\mathbb{R}$, but it is strictly larger than the set of integers.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! This is very interesting and useful

Comment: Essentially the same problem as [this old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246250/bijection-between-mathbbz-longmapsto-mathbbr).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I believe you wrote a very good [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979177/does-1-0000000000-cdots-1-with-an-infinite-number-of-0-in-it-exist) about why "$1.000\ldots001$" is not the decimal representation of a real number, which Dsf might find enlightening. Dsf, you might also be interested in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623917/why-does-an-argument-similiar-to-0-999-1-show-999-1) post about $99999\ldots$, which is again not a real number.